# Cardinality question about continuous bijections

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity

I have been thinking about continuous bijections that map some non-empty open path-connected set $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ onto some non-empty open path-connected $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and I got slightly interested in the number of them.

So, if $S_f(D,E)$ is the set of all bijections $f$ which are continuous and map non-empty open path-connected set $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ onto non-empty open path-connected $E \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is there a bijection $b: S_f(D,E) \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: By [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) any such $f$ must be a homeomorphism.  So if $D$ and $E$ are not homeomorphic then $S_f(D,E)$ will be empty.  For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if $D$ is a disk and $E$ is a punctured disk.

Comment: Conversely, we can always "perturb" a homeomorphism by a small amount around a given point, so if $D$ and $E$ are homeomorphic we get continuum-many such maps. If you replace "bijection" with "surjection," though, then things are a bit cleaner: for every nonempty open $U,V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ there are continuum-many continuous surjections from $U$ to $V$.

Answer (score 0):

*The notation "$S_f$" is a bit odd here - you also use "$f$" to name a general element of $S_f$ (at a glance one would expect $S_f$ to depend on $f$). I'll just use "$S(D,E)$" instead.*

---

As Nate Eldredge observes, when $D\not\cong E$ we have $S(D,E)=\emptyset$. So suppose $D\cong E$ and fix some $f\in S(D,E)$.

The key observation is the following, which is easy to prove:

> For each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and each $\epsilon>\delta>0$ there is an autohomeomorphism $h_{p,\epsilon,\delta}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is the identity outside of the open ball centered on $p$ with radius $\epsilon$ and has $d(p,h(p))=\delta$. (In fact there are continuum-many such functions, but we only need one.)

The point is that precomposing with an appropriate $h_{p,\epsilon,\delta}$ lets us "perturb" an existing continuous surjection. Specifically, suppose $f:U\rightarrow V$ is continuous and surjective and $B_\epsilon(p)\subseteq U$. Then for each $\delta<\epsilon$ we have that $g_\delta:=f\circ h_{p,\epsilon,\delta}$ is a continuous surjection from $U$ to $V$, and moreover for $\delta_0,\delta_1<\epsilon$ distinct we have $g_{\delta_0}\not=g_{\delta_1}$ (they disagree on where they send $p$).

---

What if we replace "bijection" with "surjection" - that is, look at the set $Surj(D,E)$ of all continuous surjections from $D$ to $E$?

In this case things are a bit cleaner. We always have at least one continuous surjection, and again we can argue that from one we get continuum-many via perturbation ... but we have to be a bit more careful. If $f:D\rightarrow E$ is a continuous surjection, $f$ might "collapse" an entire open ball in $D$ to a single point in $E$, so that perturbations within that ball won't result in different maps. So we have to talk about more complicated perturbations: we need continuum-many ways to "move $p$ around" inside $D$ which aren't "collapsed" by the (non-injective) $f$.